# Size of buffer best practice in C/C++

Tags: c++

Is it considered bad practice not defining size of a buffer as a macro or constant?

For example:

```
    char buffer[1024];
```

Instead of:

```
    #define BUFF_SIZE 1024

    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
```

Comment: Are we using C or C++?

Comment: The answer to this question is dependent on local coding standards and whether C or C++ is the language used.

Comment: As GNU guidelines say, the best is to use dynamic allocation so you do not limit the user to any arbitrary limit.

Comment: @iKiWiXz - But some regimes do not subscribe to that

Comment: The question is above all when using C++.

Comment: I use a hard coded size if the buffer size is unlikely to change. For example if you're storing the names of the days of the week. It's unlikely the number of days in a week will change. If it might change I document it and put the definition in an easy to find place in the source.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear since two different languages are listed and purpose is not specified.

Comment: Don't use `#define` - use `const int BUFF_SIZE=1024` instead if you must. Otherwise `std::string` perhaps

Comment: @iKiWiXz: Many embedded systems, such as the one I'm working on, ban dynamic allocation.  The primary reason is memory fragmentation, a safety critical system may not be able to be reset to fix memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As general, "magic numbers" are considered to be a bad practice for couple of reasons.
1) If you name the constant with meaningful name, it is becoming self-documenting, thus improving the readability of the code. 
2) The constant is usually used not in a single place. Consider the case that you define a buffer with 1024 elements and then, elsewhere in the code, you want to loop over all of it's elements (assuming `sizeof` is not available there, for example in some place it was converted to a pointer). You will write something like `for (i=0; i<1024...`. But tomorrow you will decide that `1024` is not large enough, and you want to make it different number. Then you will have to hunt after all of the places you have this number, but only where related to the buffer size. By naming the constant you are avoiding all of this hassle, by changing the value in one place only. Thus improving the *maintainability* of the code.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest neither are considered best practice. In `C++` it is recommended that you use a `const` variable like this:

```
const int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;

char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
```

That way you can hide them in *namespaces* or put them in *classes*.

Answer (score 2):

If it is documented that the text that you will store will *never* exceed a set amount, then it is just a matter of taste as to how you want to define your buffer at compile time.

However, if the buffer will contain text where you can be informed of the size of the text at runtime, then don't use constants -- use the information returned to you at runtime to size the buffer appropriately.

For example, many I/O functions that work on files, sockets, etc. gives you information on the number of characters read.  Another example is that many API functions for various technologies work in two modes, where the first mode allows you to query the number of characters necessary to store the information, and the second mode is to actually get the characters.

The C++ "best" way is to use a `std::vector<char>` and call `resize()` at the appropriate time.  This not only makes your program safe, but also flexible.  I personally have had to debug issues where the information coming back from an API function exceeds the bounds of the hard-coded buffer, thus causing grief.  Usage of `std::vector` alleviates this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's exaclty the same. The compiler will replace `BUFF_SIZE` by `1024` before compiling your code as a C/C++ code.

Moreover, a define is always out of namespaces. Then it seems better to define a constant variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best practice is to separate the data including the constants from the code. A well septation of them can happen with having the constants in a config file. Then you can use a library like libconfig to read the config file once and set the values in your code. Something like this:

```
const int bufferSize = cfg.getBufferSize();
char buffer[bufferSize];
```

cfg is an object of the class that handles reading the config file.

Comment: Does it work? The size is known at execution time, how can the allocation be done. I think a new is mandatory here.